# sending images in REST response(xml) from my java Web Service

Tags: javascript, image, rest, dojo

I have a WEBUI (using html and DOJO) which talks to a Web Service. The data required in the WEBUI is coming from a java Web Service using REST Calls.

```
IE (HTML/DOJO) <------ REST CALL(xml response) ----> Java WS on tomcat.
```

I have a certain data for a call

```
<AllData>
<DataList>
<type>A</type>
<xcoord>20</xcoord>
<ycoord>20</ycoord>
<length>250</length>
<width>350</width>
<imageName>images/myPic.jpg</imageName>
</DataList>
</AllData>
```

But in this case, if I have a list of data, for rendering each image, I have to do a http call again to my server.

Instead, I came to know that I can embed the image itself in the REST XML response.
I know I can read the image through `ImageIO`/`BufferedImage` classes in Java. But if I use the same to send the data which is read, is it possible to render the image on Dojo?

If there is any other method where I can send the image in the REST Response (XML or JSON) and using Dojo render the same, please let me know.

Comment: I have some improvement..
i got the method how to embedd the image in xml response of java. 
By reading the image to 'BufferedImage'  and then copy it to 'ByteArrayOutputStream' and include it in my rest POJO class.

I am not really sure if this is efficient and how to render the same in DOJO UI.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I could think of is [Data URL](http://dataurl.net/#about). It allows you to store the entire image in URL form. On the client, you can insert an `<img>` tag with `src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGOD......` and you're done.

The drawback of this is, that the encoding overhead is huge, you'll save a request, but the data to transfer is bigger. I only used this approach in CSS files for tiny icons, where it's reasonable.

But I'd think about it again. Is that one more request really that bad? If not, you can run the same approach as above, just with a normal URL (in case your images are accessible from the web).